# Attach existing policies directly for programatically access to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am creating a user that needs a read and write access to S3 programatically.

Under "Attach existing policies directly" there are too many policies and I don't know which of them is the one I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to grant one IAM User access to **do anything** in Amazon S3, you can simply attach the `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy, which grants:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, this lets them do **anything** (including deleting buckets). Normally, people would be assigned specific permissions for a given bucket, such as this **inline policy**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that some actions apply to the bucket itself, while other applies to the contents (`/*`) of the bucket.